# Updating Slide from Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-slides

I've google sheet where I update some table using importxml function, and I also get images through it.

I am trying to update the images getting from importxml function to slides table

Table in sheet:-
[image]

Table is slide:-

[image]

I am currently using this method :-

```
function checkking() {
   var slss = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
   var slides = slss.getSlides()
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1k5krvwszqOVPgVWhmJJyN06bo5nab8inG9_LVKt8nT4')
   var ssname = ss.getSheetByName('Stats Working')
   var Drange = ssname.getRange('I5:N9').getValues();
   
   for(var i = 0 ; i < slides.length ; i++)
   {
     var image = slides[i].getImages()
     for(var j = 0 ; j < Drange.length ; j++)
     {
        var left =  image[j].getLeft()
        var top = image[j].getTop()
        var width =  image[j].getWidth()
        var height = image[j].getHeight()
        image[j].remove()
        slides[i].insertImage(Drange[j][0],left,top,width,height)
     }
   }


}
```

But as you can see images are not getting in proper order, like in sheet, I also want to update the table content
Can someone guide me, the right method to do it?

Comment: In your situation, if the images in the sheet are retrieved from the URLs, I think that when the URLs are used, your goal might be simply achieved. How are you retrieving the images to your Spreadsheet?

Comment: HI @Tanaike, through import XML function, here is link  to sheet and slide respectively if that can help :- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k5krvwszqOVPgVWhmJJyN06bo5nab8inG9_LVKt8nT4/edit#gid=0      and Link Slide :- https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1rFRkU9-LJPYUUIDb4ueLboFtLPG6d2S2LufBK37J9aU/edit#slide=id.p

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your situation and that was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, I thought that the order of your images of `slides[i].getImages()` might be different from the order from top image to bottom image. If my understanding is correct, the order of images of `Drange[j][0]` is also different from the actual situation. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue. So, in this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var image = slides[i].getImages()
```

#### To

```
var image = slides[i].getImages().sort((a, b) => a.getTop() > b.getTop() ? 1 : -1);
```

- By this modification, the existing images of Google Slides are sorted from top to bottom. By this, it is considered that each image will correspond to the order of images on the Spreadsheet.

#### Reference:

- [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. can we also get URL from image getting from importxml(), because right now I am adding one more column to get the url seperated from image, can we get directly from image in sheet?

Comment: @ankit_dot Thank you for your response. I would like to check your new question.